# How many values $z^{\frac {m} {n}}$ actually has?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In my book it has been left to the reader as an exercise that if $a = \frac {m} {n}$ for $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ with $n \neq 0$ as well as $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime to each other then $z^a$ has $n$ distinct values. What I have done is as follows :

Here $z^a = z^{\frac {m} {n}} = \exp\ ({\frac {m} {n}} \log z) = \exp\ ({\frac {m} {n}} \mathrm {Log}\ z) \exp (i \frac {2km \pi} {n})$. Now $\exp\ ({\frac {m} {n}} \mathrm {Log}\ z)$ is single valued though $\exp (i \frac {2km \pi} {n})$ is multiple valued which gives rise to the multiple value of $z^a$. Now my question is how many value of $\exp (i \frac {2km \pi} {n})$ actually has for different values of $k \in \mathbb Z$? Can we consider $\exp (i \frac {2km \pi} {n})$ as the $n$-th roots of unity for $k = 0, 1, 2, \cdots , {n-1}$? If it is not the case then for some $k_1 , k_2$ with $0 \leq k_1 < k_2 < n$ we would have $\exp (i \frac {2k_1 m \pi} {n}) = \exp (i \frac {2k_2 m \pi} {n})$ $\implies$ $\exp (i \frac {2(k_2 - k_1) m \pi} {n}) = 1$ i.e.  $\frac {2(k_2 - k_1) m \pi} {n} = 2k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$. So $k = \frac {m(k_2 - k_1)} {n}$. Since $\gcd (m,n) = 1$ we have that $n \nmid m$. So it follows that $n | (k_2 - k_1)$, a contradiction since $k_2 - k_1 < n$. So $z^a$ has at least $n$ distinct values.
Also from the expression of $\exp (i \frac {2km \pi} {n})$ it follows that $z^a$ has at most $n$ distinct values since $\exp (i \frac {2k \pi} {n})$ are the $n$-th roots of unity for $k = 0,1,2, \cdots , {n-1}$. Hence $z^a$ has exactly $n$ distinct values.

Please check whether the above reasoning correct or not.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more simple than that. Assuming that $m$ and $n$ are co-prime, what $z^{\frac mn}$ means is: any complex number $w$ such that $w^n=z^m$. If $z=0$, then $w$ must be $0$. Otherwise, $z^m$ has $n$ $n^\text{nt}$-roots (because every non-zero complex number has $n$ $n^\text{nt}$-roots).

If $m$ and $n$ are not co-prime, you just simplify the fraction first.